# Regex return a previous match as a match

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have a regex that matches [String] and ID. Sometimes, the second, third, etc. instance of [String] has ID lines that are blank, but the first instance of [String] always has an ID line. Right now, the 2nd, 3rd, etc. instance are returning null ID as they should because the line is blank. I am trying to retrieve the ID match from the first instance of [String] and assign it to the other instances of the same [String].
Example:

```
[String]
ID=18EEEEEE //
Blah
Blah
Blah
Var=Blah unsigned 8,8 /name:"Blah" /number:2542
Var=Blah unsigned 40,24 /name:"Blah" /number:2543
Output: String, EEEE, 8,8, Blah, 2542, 40,24, Blah, 2543

[String] 'Shares same ID as above because it is same name [String], but currently ID is blank. Need the above ID (EEEE)
Blah
Blah
Var=Blah unsigned 8,8 /name:"Blah" /number:2544
Var=Blah unsigned 40,24 /name:"Blah" /number:2545
Output: String, 8,8, Blah, 2544, 40,24, Blah, 2545. 
Ideal Output: String, EEEE, 8,8, Blah, 2544, 40,24, Blah, 2545
```

```
Function ReadFile() As List(Of Mapping)
        Dim mappings As New List(Of Mapping)()
        Dim P, line, startPosition, totalLength, id, name, number As String
        Dim m As Match
        Dim lastId As String
        Do
            Dim mapping As New Mapping()
            line = reader.ReadLine
            If line Is Nothing Then Continue Do
            m = Regex.Match(line, "^\[(\w+)\]")
            P = m.Groups(1).ToString()
            mapping.P = P
            ' Grab that code
            If m.Groups.Count > 1 Then
                ' Read the next line after the code and get the 4 digits
                'If next line is blank with no ID, use the previous ID from the 4 digit match
                line = reader.ReadLine
                m = Regex.Match(line, "ID=\w\w(\w\w\w\w)")
                id = m.Groups(1).ToString()
                If m.Success Then
                    mapping.id = id
                    lastId = id
                Else
                    mapping.id = id
                    id = lastId
                End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, all you need to do is store the last-encountered ID in a variable so you can keep using that value, as needed, until it changes.  So, for instance, see where I added the `lastId` variable into your code:

```
Function ReadFile() As List(Of Mapping)
    Dim mappings As New List(Of Mapping)()
    Dim P, line, startPosition, totalLength, id, name, number As String
    Dim m As Match
    Dim lastId As String  ' *** Here ***
    Do
        Dim mapping As New Mapping()
        line = reader.ReadLine
        If line Is Nothing Then Continue Do
        m = Regex.Match(line, "^\[(\w+)\]")
        P = m.Groups(1).ToString()
        mapping.P = P
        ' Grab that code
        If m.Groups.Count > 1 Then
            line = reader.ReadLine
            m = Regex.Match(line, "ID=\w\w(\w\w\w\w)")
            If m.Success Then
                id = lastId  ' *** Here ***
            Else
                id = m.Groups(1).ToString()
                mapping.id = id
                lastId = id  ' *** Here ***
            End If
```

Comment: Okay, this makes sense. I am having issues with `If m Is "" Then`. I entered break mode, on the second iteration when ID line is missing, m = {} and always goes to the Else part and still returns an empty ID. I tried using `m.Length = 0`, `m.Value = ""` still doesn't seem to work. I even tried above in my edited code with `If id = "" Then` and still not working. Id did in fact `= ("")` when I was in break mode.

Comment: m is a Match object, not a string.  You’ll need to use m.Value, if I remember correctly.

Comment: Also, Match has a Boolean property that lets you know if the pattern was found or not.  I forget what it’s called: Success, or IsMatch, or something like that.

Comment: Yup! I used `m.Success` thank you Steven

Answer (score 1):

If the additional instances of [String] are always after the first one like in your example, you don't need to do much else. Do not set a new value to the ID and it will retain the previous one while it is looping through the rest of the lines. As long as you do not set it to null it will not be null.

So in the code above, simply do not do anything if the regex does not match.

Comment: This makes sense to me in english. How do I translate that regex does not match to code? I have tried some different options like `m Is ""`, `m.Value = 0`, etc. That doesn't seem to trigger the `does not match regex` part. I understand because the ID line is missing completely so there shouldn't be a match.

Comment: Change it to `If Not m.Success Then`. Or a cleaner way would be to erase the top if block and simply only do the "else" logic if m.Success is true. Example:
`If m.Success Then [do match logic] End If`